# How to display the command and avoid code injection

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I'm playing with `wget`, and I basically do a script that download a page, grep some information on this page, and then `wget` another page depending on these informations. So basically, my code looks like

```
defautltCommand="wget -v"
formValue=$(cat myfileA.html | get_field_value )
command="${defaultCommand} --post-data=\"myfield=${formValue}\""
echo "Command 3: ${command}"
echo "${command}" | bash
```

However, this solution has several problems, the main one is that if the html file has some evil values (like `" google.com; <evil command>; ls "`), then it could do code injection. And because my script should be run as root as a NetworkManager script... I'd like to be sure that it's not possible to inject code. However, I like the idea to write the command that will be used, it's quite useful to debug when an error occurs.

Do you have a nice way to be sure that I can't get any code injection? Or maybe you have a still better way to proceed? The first idea I got was to replace all quote like this: `... | sed 's/"/\\/g"'`, but I'm not sure that I capture all the possible ways to inject code.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks to me like you are directly injecting code to bash.

Comment: @A.B I can't, just because the value of the argument are taken from the file, and I can't list all of them, because they looks like "A5h4f121SDEfdsZPfkshf457dsFJqsd"...

Comment: @JeffSchaller Well I'm injecting a code that I want into bash (basically a wget command), but I would like to avoid a bad user to inject also bad requests, like "rm -rf /"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to log a command, you can use the standard `xtrace` mechanism:

```
log_cmd() {
  local - # assuming ash-based shells or bash-4.4+
          # see set -o localoptions in zsh or use
          # function log_cmd { syntax in AT&T ksh
          # or replace {...;} with (...) POSIXly (but
          # spawns a subshell)

  typeset PS4="$1"; shift
  set -o xtrace

  "$@"
}

# here assuming a shell with arrays like ksh93, zsh, bash, yash
defautltCommand=(wget -v)
formValue=$(<myfileA.html get_field_value)
command=("${defaultCommand[@]}" "--post-data=myfield=$formValue")
log_cmd 'Command 3: ' "${command[@]}"
```

That way, you're never invoking a shell's interpreter on arbitrary data.

Answer (score 5):

Piping code into a shell is almost always wrong. Here, you're already running code in a shell, there's absolutely no reason to run another shell.

Furthermore, don't build commands by putting their parts into a string. A command is a list of strings; if you try to stuff it into a string, you lose the distinction between spaces that separate arguments and spaces inside arguments, *and* [you'll run into additional issues when you try to split the string to run it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/), some of which have [security implications](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells). But you don't need that here anyway. You're overcomplicating things.

```
form_value=$(cat myfileA.html | get_field_value )
wget -v --post-data="$form_value"
```

If you want the `wget -v` part to be variable, but **under the control of your script**, and you know that the parts won't contain any whitespace or any of `\[*?`, then you can put that part into a variable.

```
wget='wget'
if [ -n "$verbose" ]; then
  wget="$wget -v"
fi
form_value=$(cat myfileA.html | get_field_value )
$wget --post-data="$form_value"
```

If your script runs under ksh or bash or zsh, but not if it runs under plain sh, you can put the command in an array.

```
#!/bin/ksh
…
download=(wget -v --post-data="$form_value")
…
"${download[@]}"
```

When echoing the content, [beware of control characters that may cause your terminal to perform actions or may misrepresent what is really printed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39118/how-can-i-protect-myself-from-this-kind-of-clipboard-abuse).

```
echo "$wget --post-data=$form_value" | tr -c '[:print:]' '?'
```

Comment: I like your explanation, but the "echo" thing makes me duplicate my code I guess no?

Answer (score 0):

If your argument looks like "A5h4f121SDEfdsZPfkshf457dsFJqsd" you could remove all non-alphanumerics using sed.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# sample function just not to think how to process your form
get_field_value () {
   echo "ls -la; ps -ef;\"find . -iname test.txt\";  \`date +%Y%m%d\`"
}

# out of the bad command will be:
get_field_value
# >> ls -la; ps -ef;"find . -iname test.txt";  `date +%Y%m%d`

# your script begins here

#sample url
url="www.google.com"

# suggesting you have your file near your script
formValue=$(cat myfileA.html | get_field_value )

# remove all non-alphanumerics using sed
# formValue=$(echo "$formValue" | sed -e "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g")
formValue=$(echo "$formValue" | sed -e "s/[^[:alnum:]]//g")
echo "Command 3: wget -v --post-data=\"$formValue\""
# >> Command 3: wget -v --post-data="lslapseffindinametesttxtdateYmd"


# run your command
wget -v --post-data="myfield=${formValue}" "$url"
```

in this case all non-alphanumerics will be removed and the code will not be able to hurt